# Installing and using pip, "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python, pip

I followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/2327821) instructions for installing pip on Windows 7. When I try to install the example package with `pip install httpie` (or any other package), it gives me the following error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It also highlights the word install. And that's it. I am using Python 3.3.1 and used the corresponding installers in the instructions at the link above. Finally, I apologize if you consider this a duplicate, but Stack Overflow will not allow me to post on the answer in the original thread and I am getting an error message that they do not discuss.

Comment: Same issue was experienced however the command executed in shell, and resolved by erasing python-pip (yum erase python-pip) and again installing (yum install python-pip). It might be helpful in some cases.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should type that in the command prompt, not in Python.

Answer (score 10):

You're typing those commands in Python. They are not Python commands, they are shell commands. Type them in your shell!