# python3 -m spacy download en command gives Invalid Syntax error

Tags: python, model, spacy

I've installed spaCy, however to use the language models (en and de), I need to download them using the following commands:

```
python -m spacy download en
python -m spacy download de
```

However, this always throws the following error:

[Spacy Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg0HR.jpg)

Not sure what is wrong here, can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: The command you entered in your screenshot is `python3` but your post asks about `python`. Which one are you using?

Comment: I've tried with both, none works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing and using pip, "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744821/installing-and-using-pip-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax)

Comment: Its clear from the screenshot he is running python command in python

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but hope it helps others, are you typing that command in your Python IDE (Jupyter, PyCharm etc.)? You need to type it in your shell command, after you run it in shell, then you can open it in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

To help someone in the future.
If you are using spyder run `spacy download en` in your anaconda prompt instead of your spyder console